# How to direct web traffic via php throuh a specific interface?

Tags: php, curl, routes

How would I direct specific traffic to an interface? For example each interface is assigned a different ip-address, I would like to call http traffic via php to eth0 for some traffic and eth1 for other traffic.
using using curl(using curl_init($url) )

Comment: What function are you running? curl? file_get_contents? etc?

Comment: using curl_init($url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like the answer is:
curl_setopt($curlh, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, "eth0");